# Does the concept of t'hy'la ever appear in any of the series?

Tags: star-trek, canon

A piece of Star Trek lore that appears commonly in fan-fiction is that of t'hy'la, which is a friend, brother, and/or lover. From what I've read, this was [introduced](https://fanlore.org/wiki/T%27hy%27la_(Vulcan_term)) by Gene Roddenberry in a footnote in the novelization of Star Trek: The Motion Picture.

After that novelization came out, was this phrase ever referenced or mentioned in any of the canon series? Is there any equivalent to it?

Comment: The term appeared in connection with Ilia and Decker, though I don't recall hearing the word in TMP (haven't seen the movie in 25 years or so, though).

Comment: I don't think it was in the film itself, just in some random footnote of the novelization.

Comment: Dwellers in the Crucible by [Margaret Wander Bonanno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Wander_Bonanno) has the t'hy'la concept as a central theme.

Sadly, I don't know how that book fits the canon.